# Secured ways to check if a node is up working?

Tags: stellar-core, security

To monitor nodes' healthiness, there are tools for Bitcoin and Ethereum (e.g. https://github.com/cubedro/eth-net-intelligence-api). Some of them are tools that sends heartbeats representing an uprunning node.

Currently, for Stellar-Core, I set `PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=true`, and my firewall limits that port from external access.

Other than tuning firewall policies, is there any other way / tools for external parties to check my node healthiness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the latest ledger header from horizon, for instance the following command would work from the command line:

```
curl 'https://horizon.stellar.org/ledgers?limit=1&order=desc'
```

Obviously substitute the node you actually care about for `horizon.stellar.org`.

The `sequence` and `closed_at` fields give you the ledger number and close time, which will give you an indication of how recently the node reached consensus.  If you are worried about actual forks from misconfigured quorum slices, then you can look at the `hash` and `prev_hash` fields and make sure those match the same ledger number at other validators.

More documentation is available in the [ledger endpoint description](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/ledger.html) in the REST API documentation.

Comment: Thanks mate, good solution! but any way to check it more intensively? From this method, any malfunctioning cannot be detected in 5 seconds... It may matter in the way that my Core/Horizon is still trying to take in transactions, although it is down.

Comment: I mean technically your node has not malfunctioned until it fails to process ledger close at the next 5-second interval.  I guess you could try to connect to stellar-core over TCP to make sure the unix process hasn't died, but that's not secure.